# How to remove certain entries in a data frame based on values within the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently coding in Google Colab in Python. I've imported a dataset using its url from ERDDAP, a site used by NOAA for underwater glider data.

I need to take a dataset and remove all entries into the set if they have a depth value greater than 5.

This is what I started with:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

This is what I use to load the dataset:

`data = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=[1], parse_dates=['time'], index_col='time')`

Viewing the dataset:
`data.head()`

And this is what it returns:

```
                     profile_id latitude    longitude   depth   temperature salinity density
time                            
2017-04-24 13:22:53+00:00   1   40.326608   -73.89096   3.71    9.8211  27.334680   1021.01870
2017-04-24 13:22:53+00:00   1   40.326608   -73.89096   4.57    9.8747  28.146105   1021.64660
2017-04-24 13:22:53+00:00   1   40.326608   -73.89096   5.35    9.8602  28.846857   1022.19850
2017-04-24 13:22:53+00:00   1   40.326608   -73.89096   6.45    9.8179  29.451948   1022.68180
2017-04-24 13:22:53+00:00   1   40.326608   -73.89096   7.05    9.8795  29.601862   1022.79175
```

(just to get an idea of what I'm working with).

I'm not very good at coding so any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm just trying to look for a place to start. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will change the dataframe to just have stuff less that 5

```
df = df[df.depth < 5]
```